# Is there a way to automatically submit a form after text is populated via $_GET?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am bringing a value to a page via $_GET and inserting it into my search textbox. The box is an auto complete using ajax. The problem is that when it is dropped into the search box it doesn't auto search. It needs me to press a key to fire off. Is there an easy way to get it to submit after the value is inserted? Or maybe a different method for accomplishing this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Type your search here" '.(isset($_GET['search']) ? 'value="'.$_GET['search'].'"' : "").' />
</div>
```

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    load_data(1);

    function load_data(page, query = '')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
      var page = $(this).data('page_number');
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(page, query);
    });

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(1, query);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: So what is doing the search? What event triggers it? What does it call? We need some details so we can answer it without guessing.

Comment: I just posted the javascript.

Comment: The GET is in the text box inside the if statement. Where would that go in the code? I can find my way around PHP all day but am an extreme novice in javascript.

Comment: Ah, my bad, thought you had a typo for $.get :)

Comment: Change your first line `load_data(1);` to `load_data(1, $('#search_box').val());`

Comment: freedom-m, that works perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are using jQuery it is as simple as triggering the event

```
var search = $('#search_box');
search.keyup(function(){ .... });
if (search.val().trim()) search.trigger('keyup');
```

or just call your function

```
var searchValue = $('#search_box').val().trim();
if (searchValue) load_data(1, searchValue);
```

Comment: Where would that go in the code? I can find my way around PHP all day but am an extreme novice in javascript.

Comment: UM.... with your other code..... like how you already call it

Answer (score 1):

u can try to emulate the "enter"

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 13;
$("#theInputToTest").trigger(e);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/)

Comment: Thanks. I only need it to submit when there is a value in the url. Will that distinguish?

Comment: then first check if there is a value in the url `const queryString = window.location.search; const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); const search = urlParams.get('search')`